# Select certain rows from a result set. MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This could be bit complicated. I will try to explain as much as I can.

Say for example i have a table called "Job". In this table there will be multiple entries for a same Job ID (Job ID is not Unique). The current system enables a user to search for a particular Job ID and return all the rows having the same Job ID on a form as shown below:-

```
Job ID | Item Name | Date Completed | Generate Report?
------------------------------------------------------
JB001     Door        25/12/2012          []

JB001     Window      02/01/2013          []

JB001     Blinds      10/01/2013          []

JB001     Carpets     15/02/2013          []
```

I would like to implement a feature where a user can select multiple rows from this result set (using the check boxes) and generate another form/report form he selections. For e.g. if the user ticks check boxes next to Window an Blind and then clicks a button, the next form should display these selected rows.

By the way, I am using MS Access.

The problem I am facing is  haven't got a clue as to how to implement this i.e to select certain rows from the result set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, you want to do this. Now what is the programming question, and where is your code issue ?

Comment: Sorry, My bad.. i have edited the post. The problem is I haven't got a clue how to proceed i.e to select only certain rows from the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps youre thinking in too much code, could you formulate a query that uses the job ID from a form and the check box as a where condition?
You could base the report off of the query and as long as the form is open when the report is opened the query can use its fields. In the where box type [Forms]![frmFormName]![FieldName]
That should get you started.